# Laravel 8 - Using an array of known values to seed the database

Tags: arrays, laravel, factory

I have a scenario where I need to populate a table with a set of colours that will be referenced. I found the below works for me in Laravel 8. I couldn't find anything easily on the subject, so thought I would share. Please do comment with improvements, or if there is something blindingly obvious I could have done, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Seeder:**

```
    public function run()
{

    $colours = [
        "Red" => "#ff4444",
        "Yellow" => "#ffbb33",
        "Green" => "#00C851",
        "Blue" => "#33b5e5",
        "Teal" => "#2BBBAD",
        "Purple" => "#aa66cc",
    ];
    
    foreach ($colours as $key => $value){
        $entity = colours::factory()->make();
        $entity->name = $key;
        $entity->hex = $value;
        $entity->save();
    }


}
```

**Factory**

```
    public function definition()
{
    return [
        'hex' => '#000000',
        'name' => 'example'
    ];
}
```

**Update, Seeder can be more simply written as**

```
    $entity = colours::factory()->create(['name' => $key, 'hex' => $value]);
```

Comment: So this solved your original problem?

Comment: Yes I found this to be a good way or seeding a DB with an array of known values. I feel like there is a more succinct way to do this though. Anyone please do share your method of doing this.

Comment: I have been told this can be achieved directly in the model? Not to sure about that.